# Include and access multiple .so files and headers in one project using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple `foobar` project which has a directory layout as follows:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Foo
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── foo.cpp
    │   └── foo.h
    └── Bar
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── bar.cpp
        └── bar.h
```

Where `Foo` is standalone but `Bar` depends on `Foo` and should be able to `#include <Foo/foo.h>`.

My top level `CMakeLists.txt` file is:

```
# Specify cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Set the project name
project(foobar VERSION 0.1.0)

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O3")

# Set location for .so files
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

# Set location for executables
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Add libraries
add_subdirectory(src)

# Install library
install(TARGETS Foo Bar LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

my `src` level is:

```
add_subdirectory(Foo)
add_subdirectory(Bar)
```

my `Foo` level is:

```
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp)
```

and finally my `Bar` level is:

```
add_library(Bar SHARED bar.cpp)
add_dependencies(Bar Foo)
target_link_libraries(Bar Foo)
```

Invoking `cmake` goes OK, but upon `make` I get the following:

```
Scanning dependencies of target Foo
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/Foo/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/foo.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libFoo.so
[ 50%] Built target Foo
Scanning dependencies of target Bar
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/Bar/CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/bar.cpp.o
In file included from /home/drjrm3/code/cmake_app/src/Bar/bar.cpp:1:
/home/drjrm3/code/cmake_app/src/Bar/bar.h:3:10: fatal error: Foo/foo.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <Foo/foo.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/Bar/CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/build.make:63: src/Bar/CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/bar.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:160: src/Bar/CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

which shows me that I am not properly making `Foo` visible to `Bar` in the way that I'm hoping to.

What needs to change so that these can each be built into isolated shared object libraries but `Bar` depends upon `Foo` and can `<Foo/foo.h>` can be visible from within that subcomponent?

Note that my choices for making these shared objects is because this is just a minimal example of a bigger project where I have multiple components and multiple apps but wanted to make a minimal example for this question. In fact I have this example up on [Github](https://github.com/drjrm3/cmake_app) is anyone is interested.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your top-level CMakeLists.txt. Setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` there does nothing. `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` is deprecated in favor of `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` is empty unless you `include(GNUInstallDirs)`.

Comment: Sorry, setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` there is worse than doing nothing, actually. It will override the path to the compiler _after_ compiler detection runs. If you have the `CC`/`CXX` environment variables set to Clang, who knows what will happen?

Comment: @AlexReinking - Just now coming back to this comment and thinking about it. Re: "who knows what will happen?" - I haven't tested this since I first posted the question, but wouldn't it override `CC` / `CXX` Clang and use g++? In this example, if that's what I want (force g++), then this is appropriate, no?

Comment: It would definitely not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept here is property *visibility*. There are two types in CMake:

1. `PRIVATE`: the property affects the target being built.
2. `INTERFACE`: the property affects targets that *link to* this one directly, or transitively through `target_link_libraries(... INTERFACE ...)`.

The `PUBLIC` visibility is simply a shorthand for *both*.

---

Therefore. the build for Bar should look like so:

```
add_library(Bar SHARED bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Bar PUBLIC Foo)
```

We use `PUBLIC` visibility here because Bar's headers include Foo's headers. That is, libraries linking to Bar need to know about Foo as well.

Now we build Foo like so:

```
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(Foo PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..>")
```

The main bit of magic here is the `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` generator expression. This prevents the include directory (which is an absolute path to somewhere on your build machine) from being exported when you eventually use `install(EXPORT)` to create a `find_package`-compatible CMake package for these libraries.

Otherwise, we're just relying on the fact that `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..` will be propagated from `Foo` to `Bar` (and anything that links to `Bar`) because this path is in the `INTERFACE` of `Foo`.